# Is it possible to modify what is printed to stdout in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, stdout

In Python, overriding [`sys.excepthook`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.excepthook) makes it possible to modify what is printed to `stderr` when there is an exception:

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.excepthook = lambda _, x, __: print('ERROR:', x)
>>> a
ERROR: name 'a' is not defined
```

I'm looking for a similar functionality for `stdout` also. Is it possible to do this in Python?

```
>>> type(5)
<class 'int'>
>>> # some magical operations
>>> type(5)
<sinif 'tamsayi'>
```

Here `<sinif 'tamsayi'>` is translation of original output to Turkish. This is just an example and I'm not trying to modify `type`'s output specifically. I'm looking for a way to inspect what is going to written to `stdout` and modify it according to my needs just like in the case of what I've shown for `stderr`.

Comment: Have you looked at https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.redirect_stdout?

Comment: Why don't you just use a logger?

Comment: @jonrsharpe Looks relevant, I will check.

Comment: You can reassign `sys.stdout` to any file-like object. The original `stdout` will be kept in `sys.__stdout__`.

Comment: @Qiu I should have checked the `sys` before asking this. Just by looking at the name I can say that this is what I'm looking for most probably.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're probably looking for [`sys.displayhook`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.displayhook):

```
import sys    

def my_output(x):
    #some magical operations

sys.displayhook = my_output
```

Comment: `sys.excepthook` for showing exceptions and `sys.displayhook` for displaying other things :D Super intuitive! Thanks for the answer!